# In wicket not able to add javascript through Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wicket

I have a tree view structure on my page which is calling a list of panel through an ajax on click.

Initially when page is loading java script is properly applying on accordion in list of panels. on click of tree node i am calling one ajax function to reload the list of panels. i can able to display the list of panels but accordion is not working .In Ajax call only i am facing this issue. How can i call java script to make my accordion work

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should put either an id or class attribute to the element that contains the accordion and once you update it with Ajax call - just activate it again like this: `$( "#accordion" ).accordion();`